# Reading lines between two strings in text file using python

Tags: python, text-files

I have a text file with message where it started with 'START' line and ends with 'END' line. I want the python code to read lines between these two words. I have a code which is reading lines between these two words. but it is also reading 'START' and 'End' lines. i want only lines between these two words.

i have tried this code which is also reading 'START' and 'END' words.

```
data=[]
flag=False
with open('/tmp/test.txt','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith('START'):
            flag=True
        if flag:
            data.append(line)
        if line.strip().endswith('END'):
            flag=False

print ''.join(data)
```

please suggest the code which will read between two words excluding 'START' and 'END' lines

Comment: A sample of your `test.txt`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just rearrange your if statements. Think about the order in which they flow and when `if flag` is being evaluated. Also, you can use `elif` so only one of the three conditions would execute, but make sure the `elif flag` line is the last condition.

With the way you have your example setup, it will check to see if the line starts with `START`, and then set the flag. Immediately after that happens, you are checking if the flag was set, so it will print out `START`. Additionally it will print every line, then check *after* you've printed the line to see if it should have printed `END` or not.

With rearranging the order, you will see that if the line starts with `START`, then there's no command below that will print the line. Similarly, it checks to see if it should stop before printing the `END` line.

```
with open('/tmp/test.txt','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.strip().endswith('END'):
            flag=False
        if flag:
            data.append(line)
        if line.startswith('START'):
            flag=True
```

The `elif` version is probably the better way to go since it will save you a few checks of if statements, but only one outcome can be executed per iteration. So if a flag is changed, then it will never print out the line.

```
with open('/tmp/test.txt','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith('START'):
            flag=True
        elif line.strip().endswith('END'):
            flag=False
        elif flag:
            data.append(line)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `elif`, rather than multiple `if`s, to ensure only one branch is executed.

```py
data=[]
flag=False
with open('/tmp/test.txt','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith('START'):
            flag=True
        elif line.strip().endswith('END'):
            flag=False
        elif flag:
            data.append(line)

print '\n'.join(data)
```